# Can't render view with contextPath /foo (Vue.js.+ Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, webpack

I have an application based on **Vue.js** at front-end and **Spring Boot** at back-end.

My production app isn't in the root of the server and it is a sub-path in `localhost:8090/ui`. Here is my **application.yml**:

```
server:
  port: 8090
  servlet:
    contextPath: /ui
```

I set `assetsPublicPath: '/ui'` in `config/index.js` so all my references in `index.html` are like `/ui/static/...`

According to Google Chrome, my production server successfully returns all my static assets, like `localhost:8080/ui/static/images/example.png` but **I can't see my UI for some reason**.
[image]

As I've implemented my front-end as a single page application, I configured my server, using **WebAutoConfig** to redirect all to `index.html` like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebAutoConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/")
                .setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }
}
```

Also I use `mode: 'history'` property in `router\index.js`. Without it everything works fine, but I don't want ugly hashes in URL, like `localhost:8090/ui/#/`. Moreover, everything works fine even with history mode enabled, but without sub-path, i.e. `contextPath: /`
[image]

Thank you

Comment: did you solve this? i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Setting the *base* property in my *vite.config.js* file helped. Set the base equal to the context path you specified in your spring boot config.

```
export default myConfig {
...
base: '/base/path/here/'
...
```